# Difference Between Web Page and Web Form

Tags: asp.net

I want to know the difference between Web Page and web Form

Comment: see- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6150743/asp-net-web-forms-and-asp-net-web-pages

Answer (score 3):

A web form produces a web page. Or many web pages. A web page is just a loose concept of a "document". A web form is a type of object which can produce web pages.

Comment: Adding to your answer, suppose you want your webform to have 3 webpages. How do you add new webpages to your webform in MS Visual Studio 2012. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

WebPage is a document / information resource that is rendered usually as HTML/XHTML on World Wide Web and is accessed through Web Browser.

Whereas, Web Form is a document where you can design and develop the Web Page, Web Form usually provides features which can enable a user to develop a Web Page.

Answer (score 1):

```
<html>
    <head>
      <title>my web page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <b>my web page. it does not have any html controls like textbox and button.</b>
    </body>
</html>

<html>
  <head>
    <title>my web form</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form action="mySecondPage.htm" method="post">
      <b>my web form. it may contains html controls like textbox and button.</b>
      <input type="text" id="txtUserName" /><br/>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit User Name" />
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: He was asking about asp.net WebForms.