# Which is better to use Asp.net WebForm or Asp.net Website or MVC as a Beginner?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, webforms

I am beginner to asp.net. I have started work in asp.net webforms to understand basics and then to move towards asp.net MVC. As a beginner i am confused that which way i should go towards webforms, MVC, Website. This Link [Asp.Net Web Forms and Asp.Net Web Pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6150743/asp-net-web-forms-and-asp-net-web-pages) helps me to understand their differences but still all ways are foggy.

`Question is : As a beginner how to learn basic of asp.net within few days as MVC is something that has standard and that is something for which one must have all knowledge of asp.net basics. So which way i must go from these three ?`

Thank's

Comment: Which is better to pound in a nail? A hammer or a screw driver? Use the right tool for the job and don't worry about the ever changing technologies. Further, think of it like this. With the same question, how about a hammer or an air hammer. I'd say the air hammer is easier, but you may not have the skill set to use it, so use the hammer.

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud for developing a website asp.net website is better  or asp.net webforms?

Comment: If you're just starting out, and don't have any effort in either, find you some good examples on Google of ASP.NET MVC. It's a strong framework, and the dynamic nature of Razor makes the user interfaces excessively flexible.

Answer (score 1):

You should learn what you want to use. If you want to use MVC, learn MVC. If you want to use WebForms, use WebForms. Both are ASP.NET, you can learn the basics in either framework.

Comment: MVC makes me confuse every time.

Comment: MVC is something like Walnut, you need to crack the shell to get the nut.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to have knowledge of everything in ASP.NET Webforms to be able to use ASP.NET MVC.

Yes, you need to use the right tool for the job, but if you are looking into a career, something long term to invest your time in, I'd recommend going with MVC, since that seems to have more future than WebForms.