# How to create Asp.Net WebPage Project in VS 2012?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, project, asp.net-webpages

From [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6150743/asp-net-web-forms-and-asp-net-web-pages), got to know that there are three development models in Asp.Net. I have installed VS 2012 in my laptop, but when I try for new web project, I am not able to see the WebPages project template.

Do I need to download the template or Am i doing it in wrong way?

In [Asp.net/WebPages](http://www.asp.net/web-pages), it has a WebMatrix downloadable link. Does that mean, Asp.net webpage project can be created only with WebMatrix?

Answer (score 1):

Web Pages projects are Web *Site* Projects, so you create them by choosing File » New Web Site, then choose **ASP.NET Web Site (Razor v2)**.

Comment: I find that web site "projects" should be avoided, as they are very different from all other project types.

Comment: If you want to use the Web Pages framework, you can't avoid them.

Comment: That would seem to be a reason to avoid the web pages framework.

Comment: I'm happy to use it for some tasks. Each to their own.

Comment: It's hard to get answers to some questions on web site projects, since everyone else will assume it's a real project.

Comment: It is a real project - just different to a Web Application project. And you are right - everyone assumes that cshtml questions are MVC questions. Way too much ignorance out there...

Comment: Real projects have project files. These web site "projects" are the only kind which do not. At any rate, this discussion is off topic.

Comment: Irony: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24790341/object-reference-not-set-to-an-instance-of-an-object-asp-net-web-forms-project