# Which advantages does .net web pages have over .net web forms?

Tags: .net, webforms, asp.net-webpages

And is .net web pages still something people use?

I have a hard time finding any useful information about it, and it seems to me that most .net discussions is about web forms and MVC.

I've read this: [Asp.Net Web Forms and Asp.Net Web Pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6150743/asp-net-web-forms-and-asp-net-web-pages) , which help me understand some of the differences, but it doesn't really seems to justify the existence of web pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes - people use ASP.NET Web Pages. It was introduced as a much easier alternative for beginners than Web Forms or MVC. It is also quite popular for people who just want to knock a quick site together and think that MVC is overkill for it. It is also a pretty good platform for SPA sites.