# CSRF Token - Asp.net Client - MVC Server Side

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

Is it possible to send a CSRF token from the client (standard ASP.NET) to a controller method server side that uses the built in [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]attribute?

We want to mitigate CSRF between a ASP.NET client and MVC Server side controller methods.

Comment: What are you looking for that's different from using `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()` in a view and `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` on the controller method?

Comment: Asp.net standard does not have @Html.AntiForgeryToken, that's specific to MVC. I want to call MVC controller methods from a standard Asp.net client UI.

Comment: There is no such thing as a standard ASP.NET client UI. There is [Web Forms, MVC, and Web Pages](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6150890/1507941). Are you talking about a generic .NET client or are you using one of those frameworks?

Comment: .NET WebForms - client side